Phase shift between X and Y components of the same wave
I was told to post this question here, originally posted on Overflow.
I have two signals, I1 and I2, which were acquired from a white light source in a spectrally resolved interferometer with a waveplate and a polarizer in one arm, such that they are the X and Y components of the original wave after introducing the shift, and theoretically they should have a phase difference of pi/2. I'm trying to extract said phase difference between the two signals using FFT. I have been trying for a few days and I'm sure this is not that hard and there's something I'm just not understanding about either Fourier transform or the nature of my signals, but I could use some help to realize what that is.
I have tried a lot of approaches along the lines of this, which is the code I currently have:
k = np.fft.rfftfreq(I1.size, d=num_onda_equi[1]-num_onda_equi[0])
mask = k > 0
F1 = np.fft.rfft(I1)[mask]
F2 = np.fft.rfft(I2)[mask]
fase1 = np.angle(F1)
fase2 = np.angle(F2)
conv = np.conj(F1) * F2


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 16))

# Señales del interferómetro
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(I1, label='I1')
plt.plot(I2, label='I2')
plt.title('Intensidades')
plt.legend()

# Fases individuales
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(fase1, label='Fase X')
plt.plot(fase2, label='Fase Y')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fases')
plt.legend()

# Diferencia de fases
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(np.angle(conv), 'g-')
plt.title('Diferencia de fases')
plt.show()   


This produces the following result:
1. Original signals, the phase difference between them isn't constant for some reason but should be around pi/2 for most values. 2. Phase from both signals, just to see if they make sense. 3. Phase difference.
I expected to get a somewhat constant plot for the phase difference around pi/2 since that's the only phase difference the X and Y components are supposed to have. I have also tried using Hilbert transforms adapting the code from this link without success, and checked a lot of similar questions but no answer has led me to the expected result.

From the OP's plot we can clearly see the quadrature relationship between the signals:

I don't recommend using the FFT to extract phase vs time, as we can get that more directly from the scaled product of the waveforms (which is what a classical "phase detector" is) noting the following:
Given the two waveforms at the same frequency $\omega_1$ and different phase, and assuming the phase and amplitude is time varying at a rate significantly lower than $\omega_1$,
$$x_1(t) = A_1(t)\cos(\omega_1 t + \phi_1(t))$$
$$x_2(t) = A_2(t)\cos(\omega_1 t + \phi_2(t))$$
The product is given as:
$$x_1(t)x_2(t) = A_1(t)\cos(\omega_1 t + \phi_1(t))A_2(t)\cos(\omega_1 t + \phi_2(t))$$
Which from the cosine product rule is the sum and difference of the two frequency terms, specifically:
$$x_1(t)x_2(t) = \frac{A_1(t)A_2(t)}{2}\cos(2\omega_1 t + \phi_1(t)+\phi_2(t)) 
 + \frac{A_1(t)A_2(t)}{2} \cos(\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t))$$
We note that this has a higher frequency output centered at $2\omega_1$ and a lower frequency output centered at DC. Assuming the frequency $\omega_1$ is sufficiently higher than the rate of change of phase and amplitude, it is trivial to low pass filter the product to isolate the low frequency term as:
$$\text{LPF}\{x_1(t)x_2(t)\} = \frac{A_1(t)A_2(t)}{2} \cos(\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t))$$
This result is proportional to both the phase and amplitude variation in the signal. We can separate the amplitude sensitivity from the phase sensitivity but first note this very important point for the OP's use case: the phase sensitivity is $\cos(\phi_\Delta)$, and this crosses zero with maximum sensitivity to phase changes, and is approximately linear for small phase changes, when the phase difference is 90°! So this is to say when the $\phi_\Delta \approx \pm 90°$, $\cos(\phi_\Delta) \approx \phi_\Delta$.
To resolve the amplitude sensitivity, if the signal to noise ratio is high, we can simply hard limit the input signals prior to multiplication, which removes the AM components completely, leaving a result that is directly proportional to phase (and once hard-limited, an XOR gate could be used as the multiplier if desired for an analog solution).
Otherwise for lower SNR conditions, a robust approach is to multiply each with a sine and cosine and use an atan2 function to resolve the phase independent of amplitude variation:
$$Q_1(t) = \text{LPF}\{-\sin(2\omega_1 t)x_1(t)\} = \frac{A_1(t)}{2}\sin(\phi_1(t))$$
$$I_1(t) = \text{LPF}\{\cos(2\omega_1 t)x_1(t)\}= \frac{A_1(t)}{2}\cos(\phi_1(t))$$
$$Q_2(t) = \text{LPF}\{\sin(2\omega_1 t)x_2(t)\}= \frac{A_2(t)}{2}\sin(\phi_2(t))$$
$$I_2(t) = \text{LPF}\{\cos(2\omega_1 t)x_2(t)\}=\frac{A_2(t)}{2}\cos(\phi_2(t))$$
Note that dividing Q by I results in eliminating the amplitude dependence:
$$Q_1(t)/I_1(t) = \tan(\phi_1(t))$$
$$Q_2(t)/I_2(t) = \tan(\phi_2(t))$$
However this would result in divide by zero issues, so instead we can use the 2-argument arctangent as atan2(Q,I). This is available as the atan2 function in Matlab, Octave and Python.math  (and Python numpy as arctan2). The 2-argument arctangent provides a full 4 quadrant inverse tangent for amplitude-independent phase demodulation without divide by zero problems:
$$\phi_1(t) = \text{atan2}(Q_1(t), I_1(t))$$
$$\phi_2(t) = \text{atan2}(Q_2(t), I_2(t))$$
When an arctan2 function is not directly available, there are efficient approximators to atan2 further detailed here.
In practical application, we may not initially know what $\omega_1$ is, however we can start with a guess which will result in a phase different result given by $\phi_\Delta(t)=\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t)$. Any error in our guess for $\omega_1$ will be a linear trend in the result for $\phi_\Delta(t)$, since a frequency offset is a linear change in phase versus time (frequency is the time derivative of phase). By removing the linear trend of the unwrapped phase over a longer duration test, we will have removed any error in our initial guess for $\omega_1$.
Since the OP mentioned using the Hilbert Transform, note that $Q_1(t)$ and $Q_2(t)$ above are the Hilbert Transforms of $I_1(t)$ and $I_2(t)$ respectively. So the above processing is providing the Hilbert Transforms efficiently given the narrow band signals.

These are narrow band signals. The phase at most frequencies that are outside of the band are undefined or dominated by noise.
You need to evaluate the phase difference at the exact center frequency of the signal: at any other frequency the phase will be mostly garbage. A quick way to get started is to find the peak of the magnitude spectrum and look at the phase difference at this frequency only.
Another method would be to cross correlate the two signals and low pass filter the result.
